# Interaction between the Brauer group and abelian extensions

Tags: group-cohomology, galois-cohomology, brauer-groups, central-simple-algebras

If $k$ is a field of characteristic zero and $k$ has no (non-trivial) abelian extensions (e.g. the composite of all solvable extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$), then $\text{Br(k)} = 0$ by the norm residue isomorphism theorem (Merkurjev-Suslin theorem), which shows that the $n$-torsion part of the Brauer group is generated by cyclic algebras (adding $n^\text{th}$ roots of unity is an abelian extension in characteristic zero), hence the central simple algebras in the Brauer group split over an abelian extension (see Proposition 3.1.4 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1006.3304.pdf). This often fails in characteristic $p$ as adding $p^\text{th}$ roots of unity is usually not separable.

I am interested in a (partial) inverse of this, i.e. the following:

> If $k$ is a field of characteristic zero and attains at least one non-trivial abelian extension, does it follow that $\text{Br}(k) \neq 0$?

This question might also be interesting for characteristic $p$ as the problem I described above is not relevant here.

All number fields all have a non-zero Brauer group, so these do not provide counterexamples, and the same holds for local fields. A justification for this question can perhaps be found here http://www.numdam.org/article/JTNB_2003__15_1_199_0.pdf, in which it is stated that for number fields, the $n$-torsion part of the Brauer groups are the relative Brauer groups of abelian extensions.

Comment: The field $\mathbb{C}(t)$ has many nontrivial Abelian extensions, e.g., $\mathbb{C}(t)[x]/\langle x^d - f(t)\rangle$ for every $f(t)\in \mathbb{C}(t)^\times/(\mathbb{C}(t)^\times)^d$.  However, the Brauer group of $\mathbb{C}(t)$ is trivial by Tsen's theorem.

Comment: @Jason Starr: Thanks for the counterexample!

Comment: By class field theory, for a number field $K$ any $\xi \in {\rm{Br}}(K)$ is split by any finite-degree Galois extension with local degree sufficiently divisible at each of the finitely many places $v$ for which $\xi_{K_v}\ne 1$. Such divisibility is achieved by a cyclotomic extension of $K$, so $\xi$ is split by the maximal cyclotomic extension $K^{\rm{cyc}}$. In this way one sees ${\rm{Br}}(K^{\rm{cyc}})=0$. But $K^{\rm{cyc}}$ has many nontrivial abelian extensions (e.g., $K^{\rm{cyc}}(a^{1/\ell})$ for prime $\ell$ and $a \in K^{\times}$ not an $\ell$th power in $K$ with $\mu_{\ell}(K)=1$).